# Jquery Gritter set position

Tags: javascript, jquery, gritter

is it possible to change the possition of `gritter`? Or even better bind it to an element such as a span or a div?

Ive tried:

```
        $.gritter.add({
            title: 'Dashboard',
            text: 'Field updated!',
            time: 2000,
            position: 'center'
       });
```

(also tried with buttom, top ect) but the position remain unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change position by css like left and top position:

```
$("#gritter").css('left',"100px");
$("#gritter").css('top',"20px");
```

Answer (score 11):

By reading the documentation, it seems you can't centered the gritter like this, only ths'bottom-left', 'bottom-right', 'top-left', 'top-right'

```
$.extend($.gritter.options, { 
    position: 'bottom-left', // defaults to 'top-right' but can be 'bottom-left', 'bottom-right', 'top-left', 'top-right' (added in 1.7.1)
    fade_in_speed: 'medium', // how fast notifications fade in (string or int)
    fade_out_speed: 2000, // how fast the notices fade out
    time: 6000 // hang on the screen for...
});
```

What if you change the position with css ?

Comment: this should be extended to marked as answer, I agree.

Answer (score 3):

You can try...

//css

```
.gritter-center{
position:fixed;
left:33%;
right:33%;
top:33%
}
```

//Javascript

```
$.gritter.add({
 title: 'This is a centered notification',
 text: 'Just add a "gritter-center" class_name to your $.gritter.add or globally to   $.gritter.options.class_name',
 class_name: 'gritter-info gritter-center'  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom class 'center' into your specific css file

```
#gritter-notice-wrapper.center {
    position:fixed; 
    left:33%; 
    right:33%; 
    top:33%;
}
```

**Tweak css params to adjust the gritter notification position.**

- Make a work-around into jquery.gritter.js (int the add function...)

Replace the line

```
position = $.gritter.options.position,
```

with

```
position = params.position || $.gritter.options.position,
```

Finally call your add gritter function

```
$.gritter.add({
            title: 'Dashboard',
            text: 'Field updated!',
            time: 2000,
            position: 'center'
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing 33%, which will position the gritter near center but almost always slightly off, I would suggest the following.  This should work if you customize the gritter to a different/non fixed width as well.

```
#gritter-notice-wrapper.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

then, (as mentioned by bech) to allow the position to be configurable as originally requested, instead of only in the options in the js file:

in jquery.gritter.js, replace

```
position = $.gritter.options.position,
```

with

```
position = params.position || $.gritter.options.position,
```